# How to find the runner up's score from the score sheet?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, list-comprehension

Given the participants' score sheet for your University Sports Day, you are required to find the runner-up score. You are given n scores. Store them in a list and find the score of the runner-up.

I tried to arrange n number of scores in a list so that I can select the runner up's score from the list. I expected only the runner up's score but got the whole list as the output.

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps to get runner up's score:

1. use `sorted()` function to sort the list of score in ascending
2. After list is sorted, use `pop()` function to remove highest score from the list
3. use `pop()` again to remove the new last element from the list and stored to new variable. the new variable present as the runner up's score.
4. Print the runner-up score

Example Code:

```py
# Create a list of scores
scores = [100, 95, 85, 75, 65]

# Sort the list of scores in ascending order
scores = sorted(scores)

# Remove the last element (the highest score) from the list
scores.pop()

# Remove the new last element (the runner-up score) from the list
runner_up_score = scores.pop()

# Print the runner-up score
print(runner_up_score)
```

Comment: what if `scores=[100,100,100,100,100]` the answer should be no runner up present..!

Answer (score 0):

Note:- **Assuming rank is same for same scores**

**Code:-**

```
#Method 1
#Using remove and find max element
arr = map(int, input("Enter the scores of the students:\n").split())
arr=set(arr)
if arr:
    arr.remove(max(arr))
if arr:
    print(max(arr))
else:
    print("There is no runner up")
#Method2
#Using sort concept with set and list
arr = map(int, input("Enter the scores of the students:\n").split())
arr=list(set(arr))
arr.sort()
if len(arr)>1:
    print(arr[-2])
else:
    print("There is no runner up")
```

**Output:-**

Testcase1: **when two possess max score [i.e there are two 1st rankers]**

```
Enter the scores of the students:
89 76 43 68 67 89
76
```

Testcase2: **All scores are different**

```
Enter the scores of the students:
76 89 99 56
89
```

Testcase3: **The scores are all equal.**

```
Enter the scores of the students:
85 85 85 85 
There is no runner up
```

Testcase4 **User input only one score.**

```
Enter the scores of the students:
56
There is no runner up
```

Testcase5 **User not input any score.**

```
Enter the scores of the students:

There is no runner up
```

Answer (score 0):

sort descending the list first and then pick second item on the list? list[1]

do you have problem on sorting the list or printing the list?

```
list=[3,0,1,2]
list.sort(reverse=True)
print(list[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use two variables, `top` and `prev`, and when the `top`
   value changes to a higher value, store its previous value in `prev`.
   Like this, you can get the second highest.
2. You can use `sorted()` or `.sort()` to sort the list and use `pop()`
   and then get the `listname[-1]` value.

Comment: This was already said (with more details: people showed how to actually do it) 9 months ago. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring something really new, that was not already said back in the time.